# LWC lightning-input-field for a checkbox field in lightning-record-edit-form, the field can only be saved once?

Tags: lightning-web-components

When using 
 for a checkbox field in lightning-record-edit-form, the field can only be saved once. Other fields can be changed and saved more than once. NOTE: a custom checkbox field on Contact was used in the testing.

https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/recordEditFormDynamicContact

Steps To Reproduce:
Add a lightning-input-field for a checkbox field in lightning-record-edit-form for the above recordEditFormDynamicContact component.

For example, I have custom field on Contact called MarketablePerson__c.

```
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name="MarketablePerson__c"
        ></lightning-input-field>
```

Test saving the contact record by changing the checkbox field and clicking the Save button. Don't refresh the page. Just verify the results with a SOQL query. Change the field again, click the Save button and verify the field was not saved.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a support case this morning and discussed the problem with them. A little while later the problem seems to have been fixed.

Maybe it had something to do with the support case but yesterday, I did post the problem on Github and (obviously) this question on Stack Exchange. Somebody must have been listening.